# Errors are shown when I am trying to run mobile automation TC using Appium + Capybara + Rspec + Ruby

Tags: ruby, rspec, automation, capybara, appium

I am trying to adjust environment for mobile TC running using  Appium + Capybara + Rspec + Ruby. I've created two files:
1) The first file is **capybara_spec.rb**:

```
require 'rspec'
require 'capybara/rspec'
require 'appium_capybara'
require 'site_prism'
require 'rspec/expectations'
require 'capybara-screenshot/rspec'
require 'launchy'
require '../specs/capybara_test_spec'


RSpec.configure do |config|
  # config.include CapybaraTest
  config.include RSpec::Matchers
  config.include Capybara::DSL

  Capybara.default_driver = :appium
  Capybara.register_driver(:appium) do |app|
    desired_caps = {
        caps: {
            platformName: 'Android',
            versionNumber: '6.0.1',
            deviceName: 'Galaxy S6',
            device: 'Android',
            app: '../app-mockBLE_SK.apk'
            # browserName: 'Chrome'
        }
    }
    Appium::Capybara::Driver.new(app, desired_caps)
  end

  Capybara.save_path = "../Reports" # path where screenshots are saved

  config.after(:each) do |result|
    CapybaraScreenshot.save_and_open_page_path if result.exception
    Capybara.current_session.driver.browser.remove_app 'com.medtronicndt.envisionpro.mock'
    Capybara.current_session.driver.browser.quit
  end

  Capybara::Screenshot.register_filename_prefix_formatter(:rspec) do |example|
    "screenshot_#{example.description.gsub(' ', '-').gsub(/^.*\/spec\//, '')}"
  end
end
Capybara.default_max_wait_time = 15
```

2) the second file with TC **capybara_test_spec.rb**:

```
require_relative '../specs/capybara_spec'

describe 'First ' do
  context 'Mobile ' do
    it 'Test:' do
      a = Capybara.current_session.driver.browser.app_installed?('com.medtronicndt.envisionpro.mock')
      puts "App Status: " + a.to_s
      expect(a).to be true
    end
  end
end
```

After running I see the following errors:

```
1) First  Mobile  Test:
         Failure/Error: if e = error()
         Selenium::WebDriver::Error::NoSuchDriverError:
         2.1) Failure/Error: a = Capybara.current_session.driver.browser.app_installed?('com.medtronicndt.envisionpro.mock')
              Selenium::WebDriver::Error::NoSuchDriverError:
              # ./capybara_test_spec.rb:6:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
         2.2) Failure/Error: CapybaraScreenshot.save_and_open_page_path if result.exception
              NoMethodError:
                undefined method `save_and_open_page_path' for CapybaraScreenshot:Class
              # ./capybara_spec.rb:34:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
         2.3) Failure/Error: if e = error()
              Selenium::WebDriver::Error::NoSuchDriverError:
```

Why these error are displayed? I see that app is started, also expect in TC returns true. But report is not created and TC is failed.

Comment: Have you tried Capybara.current_session.driver.app_installed? instead of Capybara.current_session.driver.browser.app_installed?. Just guess, never integrated appium with capybara before.

Comment: or even just app_installed?()

Comment: "Capybara.current_session.driver.browser.app_installed?" it works and returns True in my case. I believe that problem is somewhere in driver defining.

Comment: Doesnt seems like that according to the error Failure/Error: a = Capybara.current_session.driver.browser.app_installed?('com.medtronicndt.envisionpro.mock')
              Selenium::WebDriver::Error::NoSuchDriverError:
              # ./capybara_test_spec.rb:6:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

Comment: I'm also not sure, but maybe you need to put Capybara.default_driver = :appium after Capybara.register_driver(:appium) block

Comment: This issue has gone. But the rest of issues are still reproducible(((

Comment: I'm also not sure, but maybe you need to put Capybara.default_driver = :appium after Capybara.register_driver(:appium) block

I tried - but it didn't help(

Comment: CapybaraScreenshot doesn't have a `save_and_open_page_path` so I assume you're calling the wrong method - maybe you meant `screenshot_and_open_image` ?

Comment: I've tryed **"Capybara::Screenshot.screenshot_and_save_page"** - but it still shows the following error:

'Failure/Error: if e = error()

          Selenium::WebDriver::Error::UnknownError:
            Not yet implemented. Please help us: http://appium.io/get-involved.html'